# bind columns returned by do/tidy from dplyr and broom not working as expected

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I am trying to use `do` from `dplyr` and `tidy` from `broom` to organize some stuff neatly into a data frame. All works fine. But, now I am trying to mutate a value based on the grouping inside the same pipe, and I can't make it work for what I want:

Example (with `mtcars` data set):

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% do(tidy(summary(.$mpg)))
```

I was hoping to get the output of `summary` per cyl along with the number of observation I computed in the middle. However, I only get the output of `summary` as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 7]
Groups: cyl [3]

    cyl minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4    21.4 22.80   26.0 26.66 30.40    33.9
2     6    17.8 18.65   19.7 19.74 21.00    21.4
3     8    10.4 14.40   15.2 15.10 16.25    19.2
```

Output value `n` is missing.

I also tried `bind_cols` and `inner_join` as follows, and both result in error shown below:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(mpgMean = mean(mpg)) %>% inner_join(., do(tidy(summary(.$mpg))))
Error in args[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% bind_cols(do(tidy(summary(.$mpg))))
Error in args[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any idea how I can make this work?

My expected output is:

```
Joining by: "cyl"
Source: local data frame [3 x 8]

    cyl     n minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
  <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4    11    21.4 22.80   26.0 26.66 30.40    33.9
2     6     7    17.8 18.65   19.7 19.74 21.00    21.4
3     8    14    10.4 14.40   15.2 15.10 16.25    19.2
```

Of course, I can get this result doing this:

```
inner_join(count(mtcars, cyl), mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(tidy(summary(.$mpg))))
```

But, looking for a single pipe solution (if possible).

Comment: or simply : `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% group_by(cyl,n) %>% do(tidy(summary(.$mpg)))`

Comment: Definitely better...still wish there was a way to take the output of `do` and column bind. `?do` does say it returns a data frame.

Comment: With data.table: `as.data.table(mtcars)[, c(.(n = .N), as.list(summary(mpg))), by=cyl]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bind_cols` inside `do`

```
 mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
            mutate(n = n()) %>% 
            do(bind_cols(tidy(summary(.$mpg)), 
                         data.frame(unique(.$n)) ))
```

or (**preferred option**) use `n` as grouping variable (courtesy of @Frank):

```
 mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
            group_by(n = n(), add=T) %>% 
            do(tidy(summary(.$mpg)))
```

Both give:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 8]
Groups: cyl, n [3]

    cyl     n minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
  (dbl) (int)   (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl)
1     4    11    21.4 22.80   26.0 26.66 30.40    33.9
2     6     7    17.8 18.65   19.7 19.74 21.00    21.4
3     8    14    10.4 14.40   15.2 15.10 16.25    19.2
```

Comment: Simplify with `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
            group_by(n = n(), add = TRUE) %>% 
            do(tidy(summary(.$mpg)))`

Comment: @coffeinjunky This is a fine solution and better than the `inner_join` solution I have come up. Was hoping to find a way to avoid re-specifying `n`. But, if it is not avoidable, I agree, this is a good answer.

Comment: @Frank yours is the best I have seen so far while there are others better than what I had come up with originally.

Comment: I like using `n` as a grouping variable more than the above actually. I think the main takeaway though is that arbitrary operations on piped dataframes should be inside `do`, not wrapped around `do`. I am sure someone else can explain the intricacies involved better than I can, though.

Comment: I commented here so that you could add / modify to it if you wanted to.

Comment: I don't think there's much intricacy to it. Hadley deliberately made a `do`-sized hole in the functionality of the package so you have to jump through hoops and/or define a function like my_summary that also includes n(). https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/372

Answer (score 2):

I fear the idiomatic way is

```
my_summary = function(x) as.data.frame(as.list(c(n = length(x), summary(x))))
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(my_summary(.$mpg))

    cyl     n  Min. X1st.Qu. Median  Mean X3rd.Qu.  Max.
  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl)
1     4    11  21.4    22.80   26.0 26.66    30.40  33.9
2     6     7  17.8    18.65   19.7 19.74    21.00  21.4
3     8    14  10.4    14.40   15.2 15.10    16.25  19.2
```

(I'm not familiar enough with `broom` to write `my_summary` using it.)

Comment: Probably, the package authors would insist that only advanced users need `summary` and `n` at the same time. That's the bargain you make when you sign up for dplyr -- you get a coherent grammar for data manipulation, but one lacking entire parts of speech.